# Architectural/Deployment decision

Tags: php, database, cakephp, database-design, payment

I have been developing an employee scheduling system in cakePHP. Now, as the application gets closer to the deployment stage I was told that my customer not only wants to use it for his company but also to sell the application service(as membership) for other companies.
The application is pretty simple and the database right now is really straightforward. For now there are only 3 tables: employees, customers, schedules(each tuple holds empployeeId, customerId and the time spent at the customer). The employees and customers table will normally hold ~50 records each and the schedules might get up to 15k.
I have never delt with anything of the kind and so I have some doubts about it.
Should every company now have its own database? How to receive payments and grand/deny access?

Any comments, suggestions regarding the case and the best practices are more than welcome.

Comment: As far as expanding to other companies you could add another field in each table `Company` and then just query the entries with a conditional for the Company

Comment: This seems like an awful small application to be selling it. I would recommend a separate database for each if it can not be easily modified to include a company field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your schema doesn't allow you to select records by company, then each one has to have its own.

If you don't access records for individual companies in a secure way, then each one has to have its own.

I think you're mad to sell something that wasn't designed and built with sales to outsiders and support in mind.

The potential customers would be crazy to buy it.